# Add items to Gnome Menu

Tags: gnome

How does one add an item to this:

I already tried looking in the .desktop file of (e.g. Documents) but I couldn't find anything

[image: menu]

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to add items in the 'right-click-menu' that appears, or like adding items in the top bar of gnome?

For adding items in the menu you can install https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/353/window-options/ extension

For adding items in the bar, like list of minimized windows you can use something like https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/368/taskbar-with-desktop-button-to-minimizeunminimize-/ extension

Comment: I meant the first one, but adding adding Options like "Start Incognito" on Chrome, that are defined in the .desktop file for Unity. I probably have to rewrite the Extension for that. Thanks though.

Comment: @BeryJu Go ahead!

Comment: Mind helping me some? I have experience with JS, but not so much with the Gnome Extension API.

Comment: I would love to help. But the thing is even I don’t have any experience with Gnome Extensions. Any way I would love to learn it to participate. Ping me whenever you would like to start.